# iOS UIWebView detect mixed SSL content

Tags: ios, uiwebview

How would you detect any attempt to display an SSL URL that contains non-SSL assets in WebView?  Just like a browser gives you a mixed-SSL warning.

I don't see any obvious property on [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate).  I could subclass NSURLProtocol, and somehow communicate the non-SSL connections back to the UIWebView.  Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: You want to block non-SSL assets?

Comment: @Hejazi He probably wants to warn the user. A typical issue is that you're using frames, your URL looks like HTTPS, but one of the frames is not HTTPS, and thus while looking at the main URL, the user might have thought the conversation is secure, when it's really not. If you need a secure connection, it's good practice to make sure that key content is secure.

Comment: I need to communicate the fact back to the WebView level

Comment: If you're using `UIWebViewDelegate` method `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`, that will capture redirects and the like, but not image loads. What sort of non-SSL assets are you concerned about?

Comment: non-SSL assets: CSS, Javascript, and images.

Comment: The `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` only captures original request, redirects, frames, etc. I don't know how to accomplish what you're looking for other than parsing the HTML via [Hpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple) (or, gasp, regex) which I assume is more than you really want to contemplate. Hopefully someone has some less onerous suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to create your custom URL cache and make it the default so you can catch all HTTP requests, and then you can check for mixed SSL content.

Here is an example:

```
@interface MonitoringURLCache : NSURLCache
@end

@implementation MonitoringURLCache
- (NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponseForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    NSURL *requestURL = [request URL];
    NSURL *pageURL = [request mainDocumentURL];

    if ([[pageURL scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"] && [[requestURL scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"]) {
        NSLog(@"Non safe resource: %@ referenced from page: %@", requestURL, pageURL);
    }

    return [super cachedResponseForRequest:request];
}
@end

/// Register your custom cache
MonitoringURLCache *cache = [[MonitoringURLCache alloc] init];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:cache];

/// Make a request to a website with mixed SSL content
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://some-website-with-mixed-ssl-content/"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webview loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: This sounds similar to the NSURLProtocol idea in the question.  How could I communicate this back to the WebView?  Inside the MonitoringURLCache I wouldn't have context as to the originating some-website-with-mixed-ssl-content request.  Maybe I could find a referer header to stitch it all back together.

Comment: You can know the website URL from `[request mainDocumentURL]`.

Comment: oooo, https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLRequest/mainDocumentURL.  I like it.

Comment: This gave me what I needed to get the results I wanted.  I do need to send a NSNotification from the NSURLCache, with the offending mainDocumentURL.  The webview controller picks up this notification, tests to see if its URL matches the URL in the notification and displays the error message.  I note that both Facebook and Twitter happily display mixed SSL content without warning.

Comment: I think Apple should have provided some delegate method like `webView:shouldLoadUnsafeResource:` which will indicate the existence of mixed content and allow the developer to block them.

Comment: warning about this code. any time you are redirected from https to http this will trigger.  the redirect destination appears as the requestURL, and the URL that served the redirect will appear in mainDocumentURL.  i'm trying to see if there's a way to detect this case.